# Is to possible to achieve the SATA II's 3Gbps (375MBps) between home network storage and home computers?

Tags: home-networking, sata, nas, data-transfer

Gigabit ethernet only has 1Gbps (125MBps), whereas SATA II has up to three times that rate.

Is it possible to achieve the rate of three times Gigabit ethernet connection which is SATA II speeds, between home network storage and the laptops and desktops with SATA II hard drives? If so, how?

Or, is the limitation of a gigabit ethernet port on the laptops the limitng factor, making 1000Gbps the fastest practical transfer speed possible? (practical, meaning that without taking apart the laptop and doing physical modifications like branching a SATA II transfer cable, etc.)

--

I just realized -- wouldn't a USB 3.0 cable do the trick? Since USB 3.0 can reach up to 675MBps?

Comment: What's your budget? Do you have control over both ends? It's hard to figure out what the scope of this question is. ([Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178394/shared-memory-sync-between-2-laptops))

Comment: I have control over both ends. All of it is in my room, the modem, the router, the laptops. | My budget isn't particularly important here because the question is for information so I can learn about this.

Comment: @techaddict http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel

Comment: @techie007: 20GFC = 5100MBps!!!! whoa! Too bad there are no ports on my computer to accept fibre optics!

Comment: Since you claim "My budget isn't particularly important here" then you have the money to go buy a fiber channel card.  Heck go buy 4 of them and bond them together.  ;) That's why we're not keen on hypothetical questions here.

Comment: I will say that on the other side you say "Home netowrk" multiple times, so the answer is _NO WAY_ are you going to get a reliable 3Gbps with consumer/home-level gear. You'll be lucky if you get that from your internal SATA HDD. :)

Comment: I say "budget isn't important" because this question is not related to a purchasing question. I am merely trying to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laptop will be your limiting factor. On desktops, you could do things like trunking several 1Gbps links together, or using 10Gbps network cards. You cannot do that with laptop, and besides, when you're getting into these speeds, other factors start to be important (PCIe throughput, etc.).

In high-performance SANs, using RAID SAN boxes + multiple 10Gbps copper or fiber optic links, you can get better throughput than 3Gbps... These are all out of the realm of home networking.

Good luck getting better than 300-500 MBbps throughput for SAN/NAS access, using home-grade network equipment and hard disks.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.  And 300MBps is still extremely fast. I can't imagine ever even using all that speed.

Comment: What about laptop server

Answer (score 1):

10Gbps Ethernet hardware exists, so you *could* get your speed by buying that.  But you can't turn SATA into a LAN technology.  (At least, not unless you're a computer engineer with the skills to design a custom network card.)

The tradeoff SATA makes for its higher speed is a much shorter cable length limit:  1 meter, as opposed to Ethernet's 100 meters (assuming cat5e cable).  1 meter is practical for devices within a PC, but not for connecting different PCs together in most cases.

Comment: SATA over Ethernet do exist: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_over_Ethernet

Comment: But there's no such thing as Ethernet over ATA, which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: Surely you could use a shorter Ethernet cable if you so wish to?

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, you can use a short Ethernet cable.  The point is that you can't have a long SATA cable.